# Postgres Alter Output Display (Opposite of Crosstab)

Tags: postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a table that has data similar to:

Date (date), Brand (text), Fruit (text), Quantity (integer), Price (numeric)
'2016-03-19', Myers, Apple, 10000, 0.89

I have a query that returns a single row:

```
Select
    brand,
    fruit,
    quantity,
    price
from db.fruit
    where fruit = 'Apple
```

I'd like that to be output in the following format

Brand = Myers

Fruit = Apple

Quantity = 10000

Price = 0.89

Seems like this should be the opposite of what the crosstab function does.

Comment: Yes, I believe that answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: `select (w).key, (w).value::text from (select jsonb_each(to_jsonb(t.*)) as w from db.fruit t) tt`